# How do i get the url of a page when the webkit browser redirects to it?

Tags: python, webkit, gtk, webkitgtk

I need to extract a string from a redirect page's url upon loading it after an authentication process. How do make my program do this when it loads this specific redirect url? 
I'm using Webkit and GTk3

Comment: Could you use [the `resource-request-starting` signal](http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk/stable/webkitgtk-webkitwebview.html#WebKitWebView-resource-request-starting)?